# Changing default CosmosSerializationOptions to camelCase causes an exception in CosmosDB SDK V4

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a problem with a CosmosDB SDK V4.0.0-preview3. When I try to change default `CosmosSerializationOptions` it causes an exception when I try to use `GetItemQueryIterator`. Everything else except this method works fine.

```
var client = new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString)
    .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase })
    .Build();
var container = client.GetContainer("SocialNetwork", "Posts"); 
var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c");
await foreach (var item in container.GetItemQueryIterator<Post>(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Exception message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.CreateQueryFeedResponseWithSerializer[T](Response cosmosResponseMessage, CosmosSerializer serializer)
   at Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.CreateQueryFeedResponse[T](Response cosmosResponseMessage)
   at Azure.Cosmos.PageIteratorCore`1.GetPageAsync(String continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Cosmos.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+MoveNext()
   at Azure.Cosmos.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
   at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
   at ConsoleAppCosmosDb.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\XPS\source\repos\ConsoleAppCosmosDb\ConsoleAppCosmosDb\Program.cs:line 29
   at ConsoleAppCosmosDb.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\XPS\source\repos\ConsoleAppCosmosDb\ConsoleAppCosmosDb\Program.cs:line 29
   at ConsoleAppCosmosDb.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

If I remove this option or change `CamelCase` to `Default` everything works.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1193, this seems a bug on the preview V4 version.

It is mainly related to the V4 preview state on which some internal wiring is pending to be ported.

You could currently workaround this by using `JsonPropertyName` on your `Post` class and use the Camel Case there.